# Radial loads on joint bearings

Tags: drake

I have been working with simulation of a robot, with some external loads. Joints in a robot face bearing loads, in axial and radial directions, due to their own weight and external loads. Does Drake provide functionalities to calculate these bearing loads on the joints of a robot? Specifically the radial loads. It may be more of a mechanical question, but it would help to analyze the variation in these loads when performing dynamic analysis.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the force/torque sensor [here](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/group__sensor__systems.html) and/or the reaction force/torque calculations available for all joints [here](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#a5b03afbfe072f83e3681cf9798121eb2).

To measure a force at a specific location and in a specific direction, you may want to add a weld joint. To get axial or radial measures, you can extract whatever direction of the force interests you.